# Angular material with angularJS application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am planing to implement angular material design with my application. i have included the material.js and material.css and the app definition goes as follows,
here is the code,

**Index.html:**

```
 <script src="js/ripples.js"></script>
 <script src="js/material.js"></script>
```

**app.js**
ar routerApp = angular.module('DiginRt',  ['ui.bootstrap','SimpleCouch','ngMaterial']);

When i start to run the application, it says

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module DiginRt due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: where do you put the `angular.js` reference, before or after `material.js`?

Comment: you'd better create a jsfiddler/plnkr.co/codpen demo app for better troubleshooting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created my angular material design project using this sequential injection, hope it helps,

```
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

  <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
...  
  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

Btw, did you install it using bower install angular-material --save?

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying that it cannot find a dependency. It's likely you included your scripts in the wrong order. Make sure the app.js is included last. Without seeing a code example I cannot be any more specific than that. As @rebornix said, a jsfiddle or Plunker would be very helpful.